# How to typeset compound math letters as in mcCullagh and Nelder?

Tags: kerning

The following is taken from McCullagh and Nelder's *Generalized Linear Models* (1989), page 54:

[image]

How could I typeset the "compound symbols" $\alpha\beta$ and $uv$ with the letters squished together?

**Edit**: I would like the macro (called `\compound`) to accept a generic amount of letters, for example

```
$
\compound{\alpha\beta}
\compound{\alpha\beta\gamma}
\compound{\mathbf{uv}}
$
```

Comment: `\alpha\!\beta` ?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Yes, but what if there are n letters?

Comment: @bert - `\newcommand\nletters{a\!b\!c...\!n}`

Comment: Off-topic: what an ugly mathematical notation!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did move `\mathbf` to avoid extra complication (or you could use `{\mathbf{uv}}` with an extra group to keep the the construct as a single term

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand\compound[1]{\xcompound#1\xxcompound\,}
\newcommand\xcompound[1]{#1\!\xcompound}
\newcommand\xxcompound[2]{}

\begin{document}

$
\compound{\alpha\beta} +
\compound{\alpha\beta\gamma} +
\mathbf{\compound{uv}}
$

$
{\alpha\beta} +
{\alpha\beta\gamma} +
{\mathbf{uv}}
$

\end{document}
```